# How to access shared files on SharePoint in PHP?

Tags: php, sharepoint

I'm not familiar at all with SharePoint, I am trying to build a php script to browse and access files shared with us on a folder like this : https://blabla.sharepoint.com/:b:/r/sites/SubSiteName/Shared%20Documents/OurCompanyName/Invoice

I've found those libraries : https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO and https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API, but I can't find the good way to access the files.
I've also found posts speaking of php & SharePoint here, but none seems to match my need.

I've tried this code with phpSPO, but it fails at executeQuery() :

```php
$authCtx = new AuthenticationContext('https://blabla.sharepoint.com');
$authCtx->acquireTokenForUser('our@email','password');
$ctx = new ClientContext('https://blabla.sharepoint.com',$authCtx);

$fileUrl = '/sites/SubSiteName/Shared Documents/OurCompanyName/Invoice/INV_123.PDF';
$file = $ctx->getWeb()->getFileByServerRelativeUrl($fileUrl);
$ctx->load($file);
$ctx->executeQuery();
print "File name: '{$file->getProperty("Name")}'\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has REST API that you can use to get specific file

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files('file name')/$value
method: GET
```

Comment: In fact, it's the authentication processus that fails.
The call to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/getuserrealm.srf?login={username}&xml=1" is successful, it gets the SAML token, but when trying to exchange the token by submitting it to "/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0" on sharepoint, it fails with this error :
Issue Type: Guest user is signing-in but external sharing is disabled.

The code I've posted above calls the API /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SubSiteName/Shared Documents/OurCompanyName/Invoice/INV_123.PDF')
In a browser, it sends me the file info.